# All project packages are being pushed to azure artifacts after build with docker

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, npm, azure-devops

I'm using Azure Devops Pipelines to build a private NodeJS package (npm) and Azure Artifacts to publish it and use on my organization projects. Everything is working fine, the project are being builded and pushed to artifacts trough my pipeline. When I run my project locally, with `npm install`, `npm run dev` and `npm run build` everything works fine. However, when I run my project using `Docker` all the packages installed on my project are being pushed to Azure Artifacts.

I'm using the `.npmrc` file in the project root to connect to my private azure registry:

```
registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorganization/MyProject/_packaging/nodejs/npm/registry/

always-auth=true

; begin auth token
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorganization/MyProject/_packaging/nodejs/npm/registry/:username=myorganization
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorganization/MyProject/_packaging/nodejs/npm/registry/:_password=mytoken
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorganization/MyProject/_packaging/nodejs/npm/registry/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn't use the value
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorganization/MyProject/_packaging/nodejs/npm/:username=myorganization
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorganization/MyProject/_packaging/nodejs/npm/:_password=mytoken
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorganization/MyProject/_packaging/nodejs/npm/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn't use the value
; end auth token
```

and this is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:16.17.0
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/app
WORKDIR /var/www/app
COPY ./app-frontend/.npmrc /root/.npmrc
COPY ./app-frontend/package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./app-frontend .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 4000
ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NUXT_PORT=4000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

As I said, after running the project with Docker, all packages in my project from the public npm registry are being pushed to my Azure Artifacts, as in the image below:

[image]

How can I prevent it from sending all packages to artifacts?

Comment: They're not being *pushed*, they're being *cached* because they're from an upstream source. This is not a problem. You're welcome to disable the upstream source if you wish. Refer to the documentation.

Comment: @DanielMann thanks for the info. I've tryied to disable the upstream source, but then when I try to run npm install it fails with an authorization error

Comment: What is your specific concern about upstream sources?

Comment: @DanielMann what's the advantage of keep the packages cached on artifacts? I would like to only have my private package on it.

Comment: Maintaining a single feed where all the packages used by your application are stored simplifies source management (you only need a single package source specified) and provides resiliency in the event that a package is delisted (see: the `left-pad` incident).